# SQL WHERE clauses not working

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause, amazon-redshift

I have the below SQL script. It is very simple and unfortunately only the where clause that determines which campaigns are shown is working.

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.leadid,
    a.campaign_name__c,
    cast(a.firstrespondeddate as date),
    b.status,
    cast(b.createddate as date),
    b.ownerid
FROM rjm_current.sf_campaignmember a 
    LEFT JOIN rjm_current.sf_lead b ON a.leadid = b.id
WHERE a.campaign_name__c LIKE '%demo%' OR a.campaign_name__c LIKE '%contact%'
    AND cast(a.firstrespondeddate as date) <> '7/14/2015'
    AND b.status = 'New' 
    AND a.contactid IS NULL
    AND a.leadid IS NOT NULL
```

Any help greatly appreciated. In another query I had to convert the `firstrespondeddate` to date in one table and use another table to say `firstrespondeddate <> '7/15/2015'` but it should work without having to create a bunch of tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OR` expression should be placed in brackets:

```
WHERE (a.campaign_name__c like '%demo%' OR a.campaign_name__c like '%contact%')
and cast(a.firstrespondeddate as date) <> '7/14/2015'
and b.status = 'New' 
and a.contactid is null
and a.leadid is not null
```

See [Operator Precedence](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE)

Comment: Thanks! One more question: In the below query I am doing a left join but getting multiple records for the table I'm left joining to. Oddly enough there are more records AFTER I do the left join to the table than the original table has.

Comment: create table temp.overlord_responses3 as (
select
a.lead_contact_id,
a.responded_date,
a.created_date,
a.member_type,
a.campaign,
cast(b.createddate as date) as activity_date,
b.subject
from temp.overlord_responses2 a
LEFT JOIN rjm_current.sf_task b on a.lead_contact_id = b.whoid
where (b.createddate < a.responded_date
or b.createddate is null));

Comment: This results from the sense of joining and is quite natural.